# Why does __getattribute__ fail with: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, getattribute

This is my first question here and also my first project in Python.

I'm trying to store instances of a class called `Ip500Device`:

```
class Ip500Device(object):

    list = []
    def __init__(self, shortMac, mac, status, deviceType):
        self.__shortMac =shortMac
        self.__mac=mac
        self.__status=status
        self.__deviceType=deviceType
        self.__nbOfObjects=0
        Ip500Device.list.append(self)    

    def __getattribute__(self, att):
        if att=='hello':
            return 0
```

This first test is just a 'hello', but after that I want to get all the attributes.

From an other class, I'm creating devices object and adding them to a list:

```
self.__ip500DevicesLst.append(Ip500Device.Ip500Device(lst[0],lst[1],lst[2],lst[3]))
for abcd in self.__ip500DevicesLst:
       print abcd.__getattribute__('hello')
```

But when I try to print, the program returns this message:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't understand really well how to store class instances in Python.

Comment: We'll have to guess what `__ip500DevicesLst` is.

Comment: The OP quite clealy states that  `__ip500DevicesLst` is a list. However, that is not relevant to the question, which is about why calling `__getattribute__` raises an error. The OP has given enough information for this to be answered, so I think the question should be reopened.

Comment: Seems like one of the items in the list is `None`. Not sure if that's coming from the method call you've shown to append to the list or if it already contains a `None`. Either way, try verifying the list contents are as expected.

Comment: @Basic. No: `__getattribute__` is called *unconditionally*, so it's vital to call the base-class method for unhandled attributes. The OPs code doesn't do that, so it just returns `None` when trying to access the `__getattribute__` attribute itself - hence the error.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yep, you're right. Good catch. The callable is `__getatribute__`

Comment: Side-note: You almost never want to override `__getattribute__`. If you just want a handler for undefined names, define `__getattr__` (which is called only if the name isn't found), not `__getattribute__` (which is called unconditionally). In either case, you want to access as `obj.hello`, rather than explicitly calling the special method (which defeats the purpose of defining a special method, which is to have a special handler for standard attribute lookup). Both special methods should raise `AttributeError` when there is no value to return, rather than silently, implicitly returning `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because `__getattribute__` is called for *all* attributes, and you have defined it to return `None` for everything other than "hello". Since `__getattribute__` is itself an attribute, when you try to call it you will get a `TypeError`.

This problem can be fixed by calling the base-class method for unhandled attributes:

```
>>> class Ip500Device(object):
...     def __getattribute__(self, att):
...         print('getattribute: %r' % att)
...         if att == 'hello':
...             return 0
...         return super(Ip500Device, self).__getattribute__(att)
...
>>> abcd = Ip500Device()
>>> abcd.__getattribute__('hello')
getattribute: '__getattribute__'
getattribute: 'hello'
0
```

However, it is better to define `__getattr__`, since that is only called for attributes which don't already exist:

```
>>> class Ip500Device(object):
...     def __getattr__(self, att):
...         print('getattr: %r' % att)
...         if att == 'hello':
...             return 0
...         raise AttributeError(att)
...
>>> abcd = Ip500Device()
>>> abcd.hello
getattr: 'hello'
0
>>> abcd.foo = 10
>>> abcd.foo
10
```

Finally, note that if all you want to do is access attributes by name, you can use the built-in [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
>>> class Ip500Device(object): pass
...
>>> abcd = Ip500Device()
>>> abcd.foo = 10
>>> getattr(abcd, 'foo')
10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print abcd.__getattribute__('hello')
```

`abcd.__getattribute__` is not the `__getattribute__` method. When you try to evaluate `abcd.__getattribute__`, you're actually calling

```
type(abcd).__getattribute__(abcd, '__getattribute__')
```

which returns `None`, which you then try to call as if it were a method.